# How to host ASP.Net Core API 2.2 in IIS Server?

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core

I have created a project of ASP.Net Core API v2.2 in Visual Studio 2017 v15.9.9. When I run the project, it provide me correct data. But when I host it in IIS server, it is not working. I have hosted in IIS server same way I host other websites.

Please find below screenshot of Solution explorer, IIS, Project Run View and IIS browsing view.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming related question. The OP should read and fix what the error message clearly states, "access is denied".

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I am new for WebAPI. I don't know much about this. Before posting here, I have done google for hosting but didn't get any quick help. It will be great if you can help me or provide me link which has IIS configuration steps. Thank you.

Comment: This is completely unrelated to WebAPI. You need to *read* the error message, "access is denied" cannot be clearer.

Comment: Simple guide https://stackify.com/how-to-deploy-asp-net-core-to-iis/

Comment: IIS does not have permission on the files

Comment: @HarunCerim It works, thank you so much.